# How to set up condition for optimx in R that variables be in increasing order

Tags: r

I use optimx in R. I perform multidimensional optimization, but  my function have integral like properties in it. Accordingly it is important that variables in solution be in order: -1 0 1 10 153 etc. Without thus condition optimx creates variables which are not in order: -15 -30 15 -153 etc.  Could somebody advise how to set up this condition?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reformat your question, provide a sample of your data to reproduce your problem, and some of the code (including the libraries) that you used. this will help us to address a better solution.

Comment: If your parameters are `a` and `b` with `a<b` then replace `b` with `a+h` and set the constraint `h>0`.